# How can I check the value is of type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Having something like this

```
type Size = 'big' | 'small';
```

How can I test that 'test' if a value is Size

```
const test = 'equal';
if(test in Size){
    //no luck, 'Size' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
}
```

Can I get the type Size transformed to array keys or an enum somehow?

Is my only option to refactor the type to an enum?

Thank you

Comment: All types are erased. The way to go here is to start from values and use them to generate type information. `const sizes = ['big', 'small'] as const; type Size = typeof sizes[number];`. You can use `if (sizes.includes(test)` to test

Comment: @AluanHaddad This is a complete answer, I think you should make it one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TypeScript, all types are erased. They are not available at runtime.

However, since the type in question, `'big' | 'small'`, is based on values, the way to go here is to start from values and use them to generate type information as needed.

First we create an array of valid size strings

```
// inferred type: readonly ['big', 'small']
const sizes = ['big', 'small'] as const;
```

The `as const` type assertion above causes the precise type of each array element to be inferred thus enabling us to write

```
// big' | 'small'
export type Size = typeof sizes[number];
```

Which computes the union type of all possible array elements, in other words, `Size` is the type `'big' | 'small'`.

We will use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to perform the runtime check.

Full example:

```
export const sizes = ['big', 'small'] as const;
export type Size = typeof sizes[number];

export function isSize(value: string): value is Size {
  return sizes.includes(value as any); // unfortunate
}

const test = 'equal';
if (isSize(test)) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuoseGjwNB5AhiYUcTKiW4AFADd2B4AC5tGChMZCoASkCfNj8XfHd5AG8RODgoYBgDKGRtZVQAOlCEGIATPG9feT5eZGlwoTgAeka4Ow1rOxYYYBEAXxERAXQpPHgiUmAARwN2UlFMLQ9XBI9u9HDwuGTUoYg2YHy2CCpVqD96vqA)

An alternative solution, which obviates not just the need for the `as any` type assertion in the guard but also the guard itself, is to augment the `ReadonlyArray<T>` interface provided by TypeScript by add an additional overload signature for `includes`.

```
export const sizes: readonly ['big', 'small'] = ['big', 'small'] as const;
export type Size = typeof sizes[number];

declare const test: string;

if (sizes.includes(test)) {
  console.log(test);
}

declare global {
  interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    includes<T extends U, U>(
      this: readonly T[],
      searchElement: U,
      fromIndex?: number
    ): searchElement is T;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FQLjimAEMATFAGwE84BtAcgCNMBzBgGjgdQFsTKlBgF04AXnrM2nbnwFDRJVIhToA3AChQkWHBjUwwOAGUcRifsMQAZnCy5UdZAFdeTYFGGaNZYAkokxCpo8DB4MIToUJjIrN6YtgAU9ngAdDH+zr6oiWHoAJT5cADeGnDBqBCUwKmUEKy54fmaAL4aPn4BQax1TAIlZXAxYVDWJAhGAEqkFMg0AIJQUCTUADwAKgB8A+XlGZRZeBtwoGHIZMoAqlyXm7kAFpgERDNUtOt0wlyopFAI9wBRaq8YDICJwa5waxQCC8ACS51AAH5CC43B58pFfv8gcAQWChsp1ppym0WkA)

If you find both of these options distasteful, you can generalize `isSize` to an `isOneOf` (name it as you like) and delegate to it, which obviates the type assertion and the type augmentation by passing an additional parameter.

```
export const sizes = ['big', 'small'] as const;
export type Size = typeof sizes[number];

export function isOneOf<T extends readonly U[], U>(
  values: T,
  value: U
): value is T[number] {
  return values.includes(value);
}

export function isSize(value: string): value is Size {
  return isOneOf(sizes, value);
}

let test = 'equal';
if (isSize(test)) {
  var x = test;
  console.log(true);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuoseGjwNB5AhiYUcTKgDyyYG40AeACpwoDDAyAAm+FDALKEobNJwAKrEXPQJAHwAFABu7AZ4AFxwfvQ5bHmFCQCUhaV5Lvh++kYmZnAA3iJwcJEwBlDIcLV4AHSY9mWheNm5wJWiAL4ilhI2dg5OA65KuNNlwIXoUGNU1YMz9YrK7Z3dwL399R5eGhk6eCUzcyKLImx3Unh4ERSMAAI4GdikUSYLQZLbKDLBdCVSrXLo5KBwECEAHoURdASoCB-YZsCBURFQPJfeZAA)

Comment: This doesn't work, it throws an error "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"big" | "small"'.(2345)"

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuoseGjwNB5AhiYUcTKiW4AFADd2B4AC5tGChMZCoASkCfNj8XfHd5AG8RODgoYBgDKGRtZVQAOlCEGIATPG9fYHDRAF8REQF0KTx4IlJgAEcDdlJRTC0PVwSPGBbw8Lhk1MaINmB8tggqEag-apEaoA

Comment: @ThanosDi I think this was caused by a type inference change in a recent version. You can fix this by using a type assertion inside the type guard. This isn't great style: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuoseGjwNB5AhiYUcTKiW4AFADd2B4AC5tGChMZCoASkCfNj8XfHd5AG8RODgoYBgDKGRtZVQAOlCEGIATPG9feT5eZGlw0QBfEREBdCk8eCJSYABHA3ZSUUwtD1cEjxgO8PC4ZNTWiDZgfLYIKgmoP3qRBqA)

Comment: @ThanosDi I prefer the following approach which turns `includes` on `ReadonlyArray<T>` into a type guard: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuokQPRS88IqWABHA+1IXMWgBQ68AOkzICGwGACZ4njC2AJRRcADeInCIKKgQbMC+bBBUEVAGwFGiAL4iImFBLFDyVFnk7PGJcAGRUBosCPIASsAsIShs0gCCUFAs0gA8ACoAfA1JSQFBoXjjAKr0k3Cgkcgh+KvTEQAWmKgAXHBVvf3ScJPEXPSoPVAIRwCi6UzAyDAXk-QNFAIEwAJK7UAAfguhmMpiiF2elTen2A31+TXwk1ESRKRSAA)

Comment: Another possibility [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71QSwF7FXAXjgG0ByAI0wHNSAaOU1AWwEMAbN0gXThfyTQwA3AChQkWHBgBPMMDgBlHPKIy5EAGZwsuVMWQBXJuWBQuoseGjwNB5AhiYUcTKgDyyYG40AeACpwoDDAyAAm+FDALKEobNJwAKrEXPQJAHwAFABu7AZ4AFxwfvQ5bHmFCQCUhaV5Lvh++kYmZnAA3iJwcJEwBlDIcLV4AHSY9mWheNm5wJWiAL4iImzA8MHohAzAAI4G7KSimFoZrh5eGhk6ePTrMJWV7Z2DLFBwIJu3ol0CqBArw2wIFQMjAoHk5iJ5kA)